# Does Kant anywhere address a possible argument for immateriality of soul from pure concepts?

Tags: kant, immaterial-soul, pure-concept

Pure concepts which are recognized by Kant for their epistemological functions may themselves serve an argument for immateriality of the soul. The argument can look like this

> Pure concepts don't contain any particular material property.
>
> That which doesn't contain material property must be immaterial.
>
> Mind thinks and contains these immaterial entities.
>
> That which thinks and contains immaterial entities must itself be immaterial.
>
> Therefore mind is immaterial.

I am interested to know whether such an argument was ever addressed by Kant, not that how he might have responded to it. Was this argument ever on the debate at his time?

Comment: Kant addresses it in the Second Paralogism when criticizing "rational psychology". The second premise/inference is either irrelevant or fallacious because it conflates properties of appearances with those of things in themselves. It matters little whether pure concepts "contain" material properties, the question is whether they can *appear* on the basis of something material. As the basis is unknowable to us, we can draw no inferences either way, see [Kitcher's discussion, p.201ff](https://ivansofronievstefanov.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/kitcher_1993_kants-transcendental-psychology.pdf).

Comment: @Conifold, Alright. That's just an extension of the same argument from agnosticism about a postulated noumena, which is itself problematic for several reasons including because categories of reality and causation have to apply to noumena to make sense. Kant on occasions admits argument for immateriality of soul but immediately counters its significance by pointing to its additional implication for immateriality of external noumena, which is however unproblematic on a panpsychist account according to which all phenomena are at bottom conscious.

Comment: There is no need for Kant's global agnosticism, the main problem of this argument is parity. We know very well how "immaterial" things like shapes come out of "material" properties even at the level of appearances. If they do it there why not here? We are not even entitled to far-reaching surmises about "pure concepts" as such,  all we have are material beings talking about or thinking them. *That* much is pretty material. But let's say there is some X we do not know how to represent as a manifestation of matter. So what? Arguments from ignorance are not very compelling.

Comment: @Conifold I'm wondering how shapes or any other abstraction can come out of matter without the abstracting power of mind. That's unlike anything happening in the "material" world. The idea that such a new and peculiar power can arise from something without that power seems contradictory. I mean things *lacking* a property giving rise to something *having* that property. It's there in pure shapes and it is there in pure concepts.

Comment: It may seem unfamiliar or surprising at best, not contradictory, and not even that in many cases. Any set has properties its elements lack, and that's just a bare set, gases have temperatures, pressures, etc., none of which are properties of their particles. This kind of abstraction does not require "powers of mind" either, just disregarding some material features in favor of others, which any sensor or detector does. Computers identify shapes in images without a mind too. These kinds of arguments are basically circular, they insert their conclusions into interpretation of their premises.

Comment: @Conifold, Still, the differences seem significant. In physical emergence of properties, the properties of the whole can be explained by the parts, temperature for example is just movement of particles. There's nothing separating the two. Sensors detecting temperature are affected by the movement. And computers work by comparing images to pre-existing mathematical models of shapes. They don't exactly separate or abstract the shapes. And what's going on at bottom is just signals and frequencies. That's not how mind works. It can consider different aspects of data separately by mere will power.

Comment: "Rational psychology" arguments are just too simplistic and "prove" too much as a result. Effective arguments that would blunt Kant-style objections must identify a property of mind that is not just vaguely "immaterial", which then forces them into committing the fallacy of division to connect, but one that no material system can plausibly exhibit. The most successful along these lines are arguments from qualia, like [Jackson's knowledge argument](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia-knowledge/) or Chalmers's explanatory gap argument in the hard problem of consciousness.

Comment: @Conifold
The knowledge argument revolves around the distinction between quantitative properties and qualitative properties which is not even as fundamental as the division between pure concepts and physical properties including quantitative and qualitative. So if my argument fails, the knowledge argument certainly will too. There is an stronger argument from all of these, and that's argument from subsumptive power of consciousness that I believe I've raised elsewhere. And the distinct nature of mental entities per OP is itself an instance of the hard problem.

Comment: Fundamentality is beside the point. One can declare what they please to be fundamental and opponents can dismiss it as mistaken and offer their own in return, as physicalists do. They will simply waive at essays ChatGPT writes, with all that "pure concepts" amount to for us, and dismiss the rest as metaphysical fables. What matters to the argument is how plausibly one can establish that no material system, on any physicalist conception, present and future, can manifest the property in question. It is much easier to do for qualia than for what is called access consciousness that AI model.

Comment: @Conifold First of all I think the AI methodology is entirely flawed. Even if AI can be shown to experience qualia, the question of whether it is reducible or not remains. So this is just going in circles. And even without the AI experiment, one can claim that qualia is physical, just a secondary property of the object interacting with human sense organs, a position with the most intuitive force. But there's no conceivable way of linking a pure mental entity with the physical, for pure entities don't have the least phenomenal affinity with the physical, no colors, shapes, tastes, whatever.

Comment: Sure, there is just an easy way to deny this purity exists at all. Thoughts in brains and talk are all there is to show for it as far as physicalists are concerned. That much AI manifest easily, the rest is fiction. Qualia, on the other hand, are a harder sell. There is a reason Chalmers classified all mental conceptual work under the "easy" problem for physicalists, see [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/hard-problem-of-conciousness/), and the latter are focused on qualia arguments while dismissing "rational psychology", see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness-higher/).

Comment: @Conifold But that's not easy nor an argument for denying they exist. "Thoughts in brain" is to admit they exist, but fail to explain how a pure entity can exist in a physical organ.

Comment: I think we are looking at it from different perspectives. This kind of argument is made against physicalists, so it has to be on their terms. "Thoughts in the brain" does not admit much, it only means that people describe brain function and language in fancy words. AI can do the same. Even many non-physicalists dismiss both platonism and Kantian "pure concepts". So they are 'facts not in evidence', as they say in courts, and any argument from them cannot even get off the ground. Arguments from qualia impress physicalists because many find qualia intuitive, but not "pure concepts".

Comment: @Conifold I understand but arguing from pure concepts has a long tradition here. Calling it just fancy words seems to be a way of circumventing the datum and the problem it raises, unless they, whether physicalists or non-physicalists have an argument. So far I have seen non.

Comment: Arguments against "pure concepts" have equally long tradition, Aristotle, medieval nominalists, empiricists, pragmatists, and that is aside from materialists of all sorts since antiquity. After Kant's overreach, they got a particularly soiled reputation. So physicalsts do not need to present an argument, they can point elsewhere. Of course, argument over "pure concepts" can be had, when devising an alternative to physicalism, say, but as a part of argument against physicalism it is a loser. It does not bode well when instead of arguing against an opponent you are forced into debating evidence.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you read Kant's level of confidence in the existence of a pure *will*, you might find that Kant's discussion of the spontaneity of understanding but especially of reason resonates with your question. For example, at one point (in the second Critique) Kant says that the moral law announces itself as a synthetic *a priori* fact of reason, yet without a grounding in intuition. The synthesis is effected, so to speak, in the pure will itself, by some kind of will-to-synthesis (this is my best attempt to interpret what Kant says, here, anyway!).

So since the pure conception of the pure will is generated on the theoretical side in the context of the third antinomy, and on the practical side it is the *sine qua non* of the whole system of practical representation, one might take the key representation as disclosing our noumenal aspect thus far. But the "axiom" of the system is then moral (but so see about [the primacy of pure practical over pure theoretical reason](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-reason/#PrimPurePracReas)), and is "eventually" admixed with those empirical elements required for us to make sense of our physically-situated responsibilities. We can *postulate* immortality of some form in light of this *a priori* synthesis of the will, but this won't be the same as a metaphysical proof that the soul of the will is immaterial (the question as such is not technically decidable for the sake of resolute belief, but only moral *hope* (see O'Neill[[96](https://tannerlectures.utah.edu/_resources/documents/a-to-z/o/oneill97.pdf)] for an extended discussion of this fine point of contention).

Comment: so what is the content of that hope; that this is me, that i am more than this; that this isn't me?

Comment: @prof_ghost it's up to us. If we are minded to be theists about our hope, then we *may* (not *must*) hope that what we are is something that God can help on the way to perfect virtue. If we are not theistically-minded, we may hope that the ramifications of our physical actions, on the course of history, can be such as to improve that history. In one context, there is a communitarianism for the self-and-God, the other a communitarianism for various-phenomenal-selves, I suppose. (We are not, or are not *meant to be*, moral islands!)

Comment: that's a great comment, thanks